# karate.configure configurations in callSingle do not work as they do in callonce features

Tags: karate

We recently switched to using callSingle vs callonce, in order to share the cache value across multiple feature files, however, the configure afterScenario code that we had, no longer works.

Here is a brief example showing the afterScenario configuration working in callonce, but not with callSingle.  Is this expected functionality?  What options do you see as possible solutions?

_callsAfterScenario.feature

```
Feature:
  Background:
  Scenario:
    * karate.callSingle('callSingleAfterScenario.feature')
    * print 'initial callSingle scenario'

  Scenario:
    * callonce read('callonceAfterScenario.feature')
    * print 'initial callonce scenario'
```

callonceAfterScenario.feature

```
Feature:
  Scenario:
        * karate.configure('afterScenario', function(){  karate.logger.debug('From callonce - after scenario') })
```

callSingleAfterScenario.feature

```
Feature:
  Scenario:
        * karate.configure('afterScenario', function(){  karate.logger.debug('From callSingle - after scenario') })
```

results:

```
10:29:45.605 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callSingle: callSingleAfterScenario.feature
10:29:45.618 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - << lock released, cached callSingle: callSingleAfterScenario.feature
10:29:45.620 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] initial callSingle scenario 
10:29:45.627 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - rootEnv is  dev 
10:29:45.638 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> lock acquired, begin callonce: read('callonceAfterScenario.feature')
10:29:45.646 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - << lock released, cached callonce: read('callonceAfterScenario.feature')
10:29:45.653 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] initial callonce scenario 
10:29:45.654 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - From callonce - after scenario 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

We can see the print out, `From callonce - after scenario`, the callonce feature, but nothing is printed for the callSingle feature, after the scenario is ran.

Comment: I am unsure what is impossible to tell, but did you try the sample code included in the ticket, to see the issue?

Comment: agree that callSingle may not honor `afterScenario` because it simply was not designed for it. it may be possible to "fix" but requires looking into the code. I don't understand why you insist on doing it in the `callSingle()` just do it in `karate-config.js` or a `callonce` - that may be a reasonable workaround

Comment: We don't set these values as the infrastructure we have, uses a common config across all our services (not my choice, but working around it).  The config sets values shared across ALL services, such as urls and environments, but service specific settings, like a pre-req call to get account info, setting of enumerations, and even authentication is done within the callsingle feature.  We can use callonce, but then run into issues with the multi-thread access when parts are accessed.  The change to callSingle has eliminated these issues but now brought up the new afterScenario or afterFeature bug